# Schwartz distributions, Colombeau algebra and applications

Tags: schwartz-distributions, general-relativity, generalized-functions

I have studied "enough" the theory of distributions , I would like to deepen some topic with applications. With some research I arrived at this book:

"Geometric Theory of Generalized Functions with Applications to General Relativity (Mathematics and Its Applications) (Volume 537)" by Michael Grosser, Michael Kunzinger, Michael Oberguggenberger and Roland Steinbauer.

You can find the index (and some pages) on google books or amazon. Does anyone know this theory? which prerequisites are more fundamental to study from this book? thanks for every answer.

Comment: I know the basics of the theory but I do not understand what exactly you want to know about it? What the prerequisites are to study the book?

Comment: basically yes @C_S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basics (= Chapter 1) you only need (functional) analysis and distribution theory. Then you also need infinite dimensional analysis (convenient calculus) but that is also contained in Chapter 2. For the geometric setting you need differential geometry but nothing sophisticated. For the applications some knowledge of Lie groups and GR is probably helpful.

If you want to know more details let me know.